# Solving an integral with a parameter : $ I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x)\ln {a})}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral
$$ I(a) := \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{\cos(x)}\sin(\sin(x)\ln {a})}{x}dx$$
I got this integral from a friend. I tried to solve this, but was unable to find the solution. Even WolframAlpha is unable to provide an answer.
My attempts:

$1$) Using the complex definition of $ \sin(x)$, the integral becomes:

$$ I(a) = \Re{\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\cos(x)\ln{a}}(e^{i \sin(x)\ln {a}}-e^{-i \sin(x) \ \ln {a}})}{x}}dx$$

which becomes (I am skipping a few steps):

$$I(a) = \Re{\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{a^{e^{ix}}-a^{e^{-ix}}}{x}}dx$$

Then I differentiated under the integral

$$I'(a) = \Re{\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\frac{a^{e^{ix}}-a^{e^{-ix}}}{x}}$$

$$I'(a) = \Re{\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{((ae)^{ix}+(ae)^{-ix})}{x}}$$
I am not sure what to do after this. The Gamma function seems to be popping up in the second part of the integral.

Is there any other way to compute this integral more cleanly, or just in general, how to solve this integral?

Comment: For $a>0$, the value of the integral is $\frac{\pi}{2} (a-1)$.  It's a slight generalization of [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2574916/16033).  Notice that $a^{\cos x} \sin \left(\sin(x) \ln a \right) = \operatorname{Im} \exp \left( e^{ix} \ln a \right)$.

Answer (score 3):

As @RandomVariable said it is a generalization of [this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574916/definite-integral-possible-evaluation-using-real-methods) so I will write an answer to my own ques.
We have this integral.

$$I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ln {a}\cos(x)}\sin(\sin{x}\ln {a})}{x}dx$$
$$I(a) = \Im{\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{\ln {a}(\cos{x}+i\sin{x})}}{x}}dx$$
$$I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\Im{e^{\ln {a}(e^{ix})}}}{x}dx$$
$$I(a) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\Im{\sum_{n>0}\frac{(\ln{a})^{n}e^{inx}}{n!x}}dx$$
$$I(a) = \sum_{n>0}\frac{(\ln{a})^{n}}{n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{nx}}{x}dx$$

We know that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin{nx}}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}$ therefore

$$I(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n>0}\frac{(\ln {a})^{n}}{n!}$$
$$I(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}(a-1)$$

Comment: I think an alternate solution is using [this kind of method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281462/strange-contour-integral-int-0-infty-frace-cosx-sin-sinxx-dx/4744792#4744792), by a quick observation. I can write an answer if you want.