# How to calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^x}{1+e^{3x}}dx$ using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, residue-calculus

My original problem was this $$\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+x^3}dx$$I wanted to solve it using the Residue theorem, but the only integrals I could integrate using it are across the entire real line. So I made the substitution $u=\ln x$ to get $$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^x}{1+e^{3x}}dx=\operatorname{Re}\left(2\pi i\sum_{k=\frac{\pi i}3+2n\pi i}\operatorname{Res}_{z=k}\left(\frac{e^z}{1+e^{3z}}\right)\right)$$By integration along the semicircular contour, and the integral along the arc is well-known to go to zero. These poles are of first order, so $$\operatorname{Res}_{z=k}\left(\frac{e^z}{1+e^{3z}}\right)=\lim_{z\rightarrow k}\frac{e^z(z-k)}{1+e^{3z}}=\frac1{3e^{2k}}$$So the answer should be $$I=\frac{2\pi}3\operatorname{Re}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-2(\pi i/3+2k\pi i)}\right)$$I know that the real answer is $I=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$ and so the infinite series must evaluate to $\frac1{\sqrt 3}$ for my answer to be right. However, according to Wolfram Alpha, the infinite series diverges. So I am not sure what exactly I have done wrong. I was thinking that maybe this is because I only need to choose $\frac{\pi i}3$ and $\pi i$ as poles, but I have no other idea.

Edit: It is very clear that my question is not a duplicate because I am wondering why my answer diverges while the duplicate only asks for how to solve it. I added tags to make it clear.

Comment: It looks like you missed some solutions to $1+e^{3z}=0$. Also, the poles you need to include are the ones inside the curve over which you're integrating. What curve are you using?

Comment: I've not done it, but shouldn't one integrate the original function by (a) going out along the real axis to $R$ (b) going round the circle to $R\omega$ (c) coming back to the origin along a straight line. You only enclose one pole, the one at $-\omega^2$. [Here $\omega=\exp(\frac{2\pi i}{3}$.]

Comment: @ancientmathematician I am asking what is wrong with my approach, so that question isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I watched a video on how to use residues to solve that integral but it's harder than from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ because the other nonhorizontal part while integrating along the entire real line is straightforward because the answer is just the residues enclosed by the semi-circular contour.

Comment: It's not always true that an integral over an arc converges to $0$ as the arc gets bigger. After using the ML-inequality, the issue is that $\frac{e^{z}}{1+e^{3z}} \cdot \text{(circular arc length)}$ doesn't converge as the arc gets bigger, I believe. You can see an example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3281462/strange-contour-integral-int-0-infty-frace-cosx-sin-sinxx-dx/4744792#4744792) where I proved that a contour integral over a semi-circular arc doesn't go to $0$.

Comment: @KamalSaleh The accepted solution in that question gives the absolutely standard way of integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^n}$, one just uses a sector to include only one pole. It's morally equivalent to your accepted solution here, where @F Shrike uses a box to include only one pole.

Comment: It is a pity so many answerers and close voters thought the essence of your question was: "how to get the answer?" rather than: "what went wrong with my attempt?". I contend this is **not** a duplicate, and your question has a lot of value as a good counterexample for being too hasty with contour integrals

Comment: Yes, I appreciate your consideration. I made an edit to emphasize this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few mistakes here. I propose a way to correctly use contour integration - using the integrand in the form you give - at the bottom of the post.

More important points:

It is *not* true that the residue theorem can only come in handy for integrals over the whole real line. That remark applies for the semicircular contour method but there are others; my personal favourite way to integrate (when it applies) is to use a dogbone or Hankel contour method and these may appear even for bounded domains like $[-1,1]$.

The real thing I want to talk about:

Just because 'usually' the arc integral vanishes doesn't mean it always will! In fact, **it doesn't vanish**. You always, always need to do a sanity check on the asymptotics. The standard trick with $\sin(t)\ge\frac{2}{\pi}t$ on $[0,\pi/2]$ tells you that integrating $\int e^zf(z)$ over those large semicircular arcs gives you something roughly of size $\int_0^{\pi}|f(Re^{it})|\,\mathrm{d}t$, $R$ the radius. Ok, so to expect this vanish we should definitely make sure $f$ - here, $f(z)=(1+e^{3z})^{-1}$ - decays sufficiently well as you go out to the upper half plane. But in this case that's not obvious; $f$ attains $\infty$ infinitely often as we move out to the upper half plane! Ok sure, you could rig $R=\frac{2\pi i}{3}(1+N)$, $N$ a large integer, to try to avoid the poles as much as possible, but then we still don't observe decay; $|f|\approx2$ near the peak of the semicircular arc. It is **not** at all clear that the integral over the semicircular arc vanishes. It doesn't follow from the standard observations, as far as I can tell: moral, don't be too hasty with "everyone knows it vanishes"!

In fact, I can prove to you it doesn't vanish - it doesn't even converge! Simply observe that the integral over the real line converges, whereas the (corrected) residue series still purely consists of summands of type $e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ is real; these do not tend to zero - are constantly of unit modulus - so the series diverges by the simplest divergence test.

Less important points:

Why take the real part of the residues? The closed contour integral is exactly equal to the residue sum, real part and imaginary part altogether, and *if* the other arc integral vanishes then there is an exact equality $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=\sum\mathrm{Res}$ (maybe taking a limit somewhere in there) but certainly no real part operator. If the right hand side is nonreal, and the left hand side is a pure real integrand, then there's a mistake.

Now for the roots.  $e^{3z}=-1$ iff. $3z=\pi i+2\pi in$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ iff. $z=\frac{\pi i}{3}+\frac{2\pi i}{3}n$ - you missed the "$n/3$" aspect.

---

Alright, so the semicircular arc doesn't work. We can still do something; a nice trick is to exploit the periodicity of the exponential. If $x\mapsto x+\frac{2\pi i}{3}$, the integrand transforms like $f(x)\mapsto e^{2\pi i/3}f(x)$, thus: $$(1-e^{2\pi i/3})I=\oint_{\text{Large boxes of height $2\pi/3$}}=2\pi i\cdot\mathrm{Res}\left(f;\frac{\pi i}{3}\right)$$Where now, *truly*, the 'error' terms - the short integrals of type $\int_R^{R+2\pi i/3}$ and $\int_{-R}^{-R+2\pi i/3}$ - really do vanish by an easy check. The integral coming back down the final edge of the box, $R+2\pi i/3\to -R+2\pi i/3$, is just a multiple of $I$ by my observation.

There is only one pole enclosed in my contour, which is also nice. The residue computation is as you say, so we find: $$I=\frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{2\pi i/3}}\cdot\frac{1}{3e^{2\pi i/3}}=\frac{\pi}{3}\csc(\pi/3)=\frac{2\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$Here's an image:

[image]

And we take limits in $R\to\infty$.

Comment: Imo the last part (which you've edited) is not written clearly. (I've upvoted your post before you've edited it.)

Comment: Hi FShrike, I know that there are other contours to use, I just don't know how to use them because finding the integrals along the other contours is tricky for me, while I thought that the integral along the semicircular arc is always zero. Also, can you provide a picture of the contour "Large boxes of height $\frac{2\pi}3$"? i.e. the space between them, whether they are rectangles, how the real number line is involved, etc.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I've included an image of the contour. The 'error' integrals are not always zero, so my message to you is to always check it - at least, sketch a proof of how to check it.

Answer (score 3):

First, I would convert this problem back to its original form.

$\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{1+x^3}\ dx$

Now we will form a contour that includes the real line, an arc of radius $R$ taking the limit as $R$ approaches infinity, and a line from the endpoint of this arc back to the origin.

What will be the endpoint of the arc?

$\frac {1}{1+z^3}$ has poles at $-1, e^{\frac {\pi}{3} i}, e^{-\frac {\pi}{3} i}$

We want to get one of these poles inside our contour.

I propose taking 1 third of a circle.  i.e.$\  \theta = \frac {2\pi}{3}$

We will have

$\oint_\gamma \frac {1}{1+z^3}\ dz = \lim_\limits{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \frac {1}{1+x^3} \ dx + \int_0^\frac {2\pi}{3} \frac {iRe^{i\theta}}{1+(Re^i\theta)^3} \ d\theta + \int_R^0 \frac {e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}}{1+(te^{\frac {2\pi}{3}})^3} \ dt$

$\left|\lim_\limits{R\to \infty} \int_0^\frac {2\pi}{3} \frac {iRe^{i\theta}}{1+(Re^i\theta)^3} \ d\theta\right| < \lim_\limits {R\to \infty}\frac {2\pi}{3}\left|\frac {iRe^{i\theta}}{1+(Re^i\theta)^3}\right| < \lim_\limits {R\to \infty}\frac {2\pi}{3R^2} = 0$

$\int_0^R \frac {1}{1+x^3} \ dx + \int_R^0 \frac {e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}}{1+(te^{\frac {2\pi}{3}})^3} \ dt = (1-e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i})\int_0^R \frac {1}{1+x^3} \ dx$

$\oint_\gamma \frac {1}{1+z^3}\ dz = (1-e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i})\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{1+x^3} \ dx\\
\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{1+x^3} \ dx = \frac {1}{1-e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}}\oint_\gamma \frac {1}{1+z^3}\ dz$

Evaluating the residue at $e^{\frac {\pi}{3}i}$

$\text{Res}_{z = e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}} \frac {1}{1+z^3} = \frac {1}{3e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}}=\frac {e^{\frac {4\pi}{3}i}}{3}$

$\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{1+x^3} \ dx = (2\pi i)\frac {1}{1-e^{\frac {2\pi}{3}i}}\frac {e^{\frac {4\pi}{3}i}}{3}\\
(2\pi i)\frac {e^{-\frac {\pi}{3}i}}{e^{-\frac {\pi}{3}i}-e^{\frac {\pi}{3}i}}\frac {e^{\frac {4\pi}{3}i}}{3}\\
\pi\frac {2i}{e^{-\frac {\pi}{3}i}-e^{\frac {\pi}{3}i}}\frac {e^{\pi i}}{3}=
\frac {\pi}{3\sin \frac {\pi}{3}} = \frac {2\pi}{3\sqrt 3}$

Comment: Great answer, I wish I could accept it but this answer technically doesn't answer the OP. +1